# Visual Studio : Select a working git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-submodules

I'm working on a solution with Visual Studio 2017 and I have some projects and git repositories in it.

**Root\**

|
+-----+ **.git\**

|
+-----+ **Solution\**

|       |
|       +-----+ **Solution.sln**

|       +-----+ **MainProject.vcxproj**

|       
+-----+ **OtherProject\ (Submodule)**

        |
        +----- **.git (File because is a submodule)**

        +----- **OtherProject.vcxproj\**

I have to work on `OtherProject`, thereby, I would like to be able to use Visual Studio Team Explorer (Git) with the repository located at `Root\OtherProject\.git` instead of `Root\.git\`.

*Is there any way to indicate Visual Studio the repository I want to work on?*